# Need to navigate between apps

Tags: c#, maui

```
private async void GoApp2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var uri = new Uri("app2://");
    //bool isOpened = await Launcher.TryOpenAsync(uri);
    bool supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("app2://");

    if (supportsUri)
        await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("app2://com.companyname.app2");
}
```

This is my button click event in maui.But the supportUri is getting false value

I need to add the data scheme in android for getting the Uri true and navigate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the package name of the app you want to open is `com.xamarin.secondapp`.

Then you need to add `IntentFilter` and `Exported =true` to `MainActivity.cs` of the app you want to open(`com.xamarin.secondapp`).

Just as follows:

```
  [Activity(Label = "SecondApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,Exported =true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)] 
    [
    IntentFilter
    (
        new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
            {
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }
    )
]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

**Note:** remember to add code `DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }`.

For the current app, you need to add `queries` tag for the app you want to open in file `manifest.xml`.

For example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.openappapp1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="OpenappApp1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">

      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


      <queries>
            <package android:name="com.xamarin.secondapp" />
      </queries>
</manifest>
```

And usage example:

```
public async void OpenSecondApp()
{

    var supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("myapp://");
    if (supportsUri)
        await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("myapp://com.xamarin.secondapp");

}
```